# Generate matrix(NxN) from a list of currencies exchange price in c++

Tags: c++, graph

I have a list of currencies and their exchange rates like this:

```
    unordered_map<string, double> exchange_rates = {
        {"EUR/USD", 0.98},
        {"EUR/AUD", 0.88},
        {"USD/EUR", 1.22},
        {"USD/AUD", 1.09},
        {"AUD/EUR", 1.33},
        {"AUD/USD", 1.01}
    };
```

and currencies list as

```
vector<string> currencies = {"EUR", "USD", "AUD"};
```

Now I want to generate a matrix from this list, something like this:

```
    EUR  USD  AUD
EUR  1   0.98 0.88 

USD 1.22  1   1.09

AUD 1.33 1.01  1
```

I think that the matrix structure needs to be something like this:

> vector<vector> matrix(currencies.size(), vector(currencies.size(), 1.0));

How can I generate this matrix? and display on output console as above?

Someone can write me an example code?

Thanks

Comment: What is even a matrix graph? There is no such thing in C++. Why do you want it? I mean you can just use a 2D array, right? You are going to have to try first, this is not a code writing service but feel free to ask a specific question about your attempt.

Comment: You know, if you have a Euro to USD conversion of 0.98 and a USD to Euro conversion of 1.22 ... then someone could make a heck of a profit on the currency markets! Anyway, you mean just "printing a matrix with appropriate headers", not "matrix graph".

Comment: I don't know how to call this graph. But I think anyone can undersand my question and what I want.

Comment: I need to generate a matrix for "bellman ford" algorithm from the list i'd wrote in my question.

Comment: @Udbdjfj -- Take a step back first.  What is the actual data structure you are using to store this information?  Is it a `std::map`?  A 2D array?  You want us to show you printing code, but how is that possible if we don't know what structure the data is stored in?

Comment: Data structure: `vector<string(currency symbol), map<string(currency symbol), double(exchange rate)>> myData;`

Comment: @lastchance "someone could make a heck of a profit" Why "could"? Someone does. Have you ever seen a currency exchange counter at an airport?

Comment: Currency names look a lot like indices in an array. A pair of currencies looks a lot like a pair of indices in a 2D array. You want to be able to translate a string which is a currency name to an index in an array. Say you have a fixed helper array of strings `{"EUR", "USD", "AUD"}`. Use it to convert strings to numbers, and use the numbers to index your vector of vectors.